# How to handle a large textView that get's cutoff on small screen sizes in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a textView that fits perfectly on my Galaxy Nexus and it takes up the whole screen. I'm trying the application out on lower resolution devices and my text is getting cutoff. What's the easiest way to alleviate this?

Comment: What's your text size unit?

Comment: 30sp is the current size of my text

Comment: If you change it to `dp` it will automatically re-sized according your display density.

Answer (score 1):

Stick it inside of a ScrollView.

EDIT: If you can't use a ScrollView, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds) might help. Basically, you would extend TextView and it would recalculate the text size whenever the size of the view changes.

Comment: Ah Yes. Simple and fairly straight forward, but I forgot to mention that as my only guideline, I cannot have a Scroll View.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't put in a ScrollView or make in 2 lines, another option is to have a different smaller text for lower resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on java by writing with \n it will gets new line.it automatically looks like scroll view.